# .net: Storing a .net datatable with dataAdapter from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, datatable

I have a stored procedure called

```
GET_CLIENT(IN VARCHAR2, IN VARCHAR2, OUT SYS REF_CURSOR)
```

I am trying to store their results in `ConnectAndQuery` data table.

It results in this error:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]
>   ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
>
> at ConexionBD.ConnectAndQuery(String layerName, Decimal idElemento,
>   String idElementoString, String conexion).

My code:

```
public DataTable ConnectAndQuery(string layerName, decimal idElemento, string idElementoString, string conexion)
    {
        Logger.Debug("App_Code/ConexionBD.cs: using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; + conexion ");
        using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(conexion))
        {
            try
            {
                using (OdbcCommand Command = new OdbcCommand("{ call PKG_GEONET_REPORTS.GET_ORDINARY_CLIENT(?, ?, ?) }", conn))
                {
                    Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    Command.Parameters.Add("client_in", OracleType.VarChar).Value = idElemento.ToString();
                    Command.Parameters.Add("layer_in", OracleType.VarChar).Value = layerName;
                    Command.Parameters.Add("client_data", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    using (OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(Command))
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug and check which line of code throws exception and what is exact message of the exception?

Comment: Do you really need the OdbcCommand? Can't you use the OracleCommand?

Comment: Throws occurs there: da.Fill(ds, "result_name"); (result_name?????). No problem with OracleCommand

Comment: Wich parameter do I need there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SQL text in your command.

```
da.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(
    "{ call PKG_NAME.GET_CLIENT(?, ?, ?) }",
    conn);
```

- Your 1st parameter "layer_in" should be `OracleType.VarChar` to match your stored
  procedure 1st parameter DataType, should it not?
- `da.Fill(ds);` should be used instead of `da.Fill(ds,"RESULT_NAME?");` if you dont know the name of the result set.

Comment: Forgot ODBC.NET processes parameters by ordinal position, not name. Fixed in answer.

Comment: The problem is here:  
Throws occurs there: da.Fill(ds, "result_name"); (result_name?????), I think

Comment: The SQL command isnt actually executed until you call da.Fill(ds,"result_name).  So you would see a command execution error there if your command syntax was wrong.  The Oracle error you're seeing is related to a syntax error, which could be because the incorrect datatype on your first parameter, or incorrect format for calling a stored procedure which I indicated a fix for in my answer.